# Grid Computing API

Tags: c#, grid-computing

I want to write a distributed software system (system where you can execute programs faster than on a single pc), that can execute different kinds of programs.(As it is a school project, I'll probably execute programs like Prime finder and Pi calculator on it)

My preferences is that it should written for C# with .NET, have good documentation, be simple to write(not new in C# with .NET, but I'm not professional) and to be able to write tasks for the grid easily and/or to load programs to the network directly from .exe.

I've looked a little at the:

1. [MPAPI](http://mpapi.codeplex.com/)
2. [Utilify](http://www.utilify.com/)(from the makers of Alchemy)
3. [NGrid](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) (Outdated?)

Which one is the best for my case? Do you have any experience with them?

ps. I'm aware of many similar questions here, but they were either outdated, not with proper answers or didn't answer my question, and therefore I choose to ask again.

Comment: Looks like they are all dead projects :(.

Comment: If you want build your own why not explore Quartz.net - it has "Clustering" support albeit with some limitation (Must be .NET and must implement IJob. JDBC source only)

Answer (score 2):

I just contacted the founder of Utilify (Krishna Nadiminti) and while active development has paused for now, he has kindly released all the source code [here on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/krishna_nadiminti/utilify/src/92970f557d30cc1a755e5b9cac4d3d03d7a76acf/src?at=master).

I think it is worth continuing this project as there are literally no comparable alternative as of now (even commercial). I may start working on it but don't wait for me :).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitelly look at it.
Will report back :)

Comment: "No comparable" can you elaborate?

Comment: I could not find another software such as Utilify.

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem. I tried NGrid, Alchemi and MS
PI.net.
After all i decided to start my own open source project to play around, check here: http://lucygrid.codeplex.com/.

UPDATE:

See how looks PI example:
The function passed to **AsParallelGrid** will be executed by the grid nodes.
You can play with it running the DEMO project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Distributes simple const processing
/// </summary>
class PICalculation : AbstractDemo
{

    public int Steps = 100000;
    public int ChunkSize = 50;
    public PICalculation()
    {

    }

    override
    public string Info()
    {
        return "Calculates PI over the grid.";
    }


    override
    public string Run(bool enableLocalProcessing)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        double step = 1.0 / (double)Steps;
        /* ORIGINAL VERSION
        object obj = new object();

        Parallel.ForEach(
            Partitioner.Create(0, Steps),
            () => 0.0,
            (range, state, partial) =>
            {
                for (long i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
                {
                    double x = (i - 0.5) * step;
                    partial += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
                }
                return partial;
            },
            partial => { lock (obj) sum += partial; });
        */
        sum = Enumerable
            .Range(0, Steps)
            // Create bucket
            .GroupBy(s => s / 50)
            // Local variable initialization is not distributed over the grid
            .Select(i => new 
            {
                Item1 = i.First(),
                Item2 = i.Last() + 1, // Inclusive
                Step = step
            })
            .AsParallelGrid(data =>
            {
                double partial = 0;
                for (var i = data.Item1; i != data.Item2 ; ++i)
                {
                    double x = (i - 0.5) * data.Step;
                    partial += (double)(4.0 / (1.0 + x * x));
                }
                return partial;
            }, new GridSettings()
            {
                EnableLocalProcessing = enableLocalProcessing
            })
            .Sum() * step;
        return sum.ToString();

    }
}
```